# Jsvalidator in CakePHP is incorrectly error-correcting textareas

Tags: php, javascript, regex, cakephp, validation

I'm using the [CakePHP Javascript Validator](http://sandbox2.pseudocoder.com/demo/validation), and everything works just fine EXCEPT validating textareas.

The problem isn't that it doesn't validate at all - but it has a problem with:

```
'rule' => array('between', 20, 500),
```

This error is triggered if they enter any linebreaks anywhere in the textarea regardless of the total # of characters or even the total # of characters in the first line.

Any thoughts as to 1) why this would happen and 2) how to fix it?

**Edit:**

The regex is being written in plugins/js_validate/views/helpers/validation.php, and it appears to be generating this:

The regex it's spitting out for validating my textarea field is this:  `\/^.{4,138}$\/`

I assume the problem is the ".", since that is "anything except newlines" or something.  What do I replace it with to allow newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `s` modifier which makes dot metacharacter match all characters, including newlines. In your case expression will look like:

```
/^.{4,138}$/s
```

Comment: Adding the "s" did it - but I had to implement like this:  `/^[\s\S]{4,138}$/`  Feel free to change/edit your answer to match for future cake users reading this question.